# php exec not working via browser

Tags: ubuntu, php, imagemagick

Server : Ubantu 16
Php version : 7

i have php 7 installed on ubantu 16 .i have also installed imagemagick.

now my php file say **index.php** with code below

```
echo exec("whoami");
echo exec("/usr/bin/convert '/var/www/html/slc.png' '/var/www/html/slc.ppm'");
```

now when i run it in browser say example.com/index.php , it show output

```
www-data
```

But convert command does not gets executed.

but when i run it via cli new ppm file is created

```
php index.php
```

can you please tell me how to fix this issue

Comment: Permissions issue, almost certainly. Turn error reporting on or check the server logs.

Comment: i have added ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL); no error

Comment: Is that all that you have in your script?  If not, make a stripped down copy that serves only at demonstrating the issue and show it completely here.

Comment: yeah it has just one line code to convert png to ppm , strange it works via php cli

Comment: For your EGO's sake, do not use the word `strange` (or its derivatives) as it will only make you look bad.

Comment: If you just put `<?php echo "hi";` in the script, do you see its output?  If not, you're not looking at the right place for the error logs or there are some higher level directives preventing them from being logged.

Comment: hey solved issue , created test folder with 777 permission and changed my code

echo exec("/usr/bin/convert '/var/www/html/slc.png' '/var/www/html/test/slc.ppm'");

Comment: OMG NO - please learn how permissions work, how code injection occurs and implement a minimal set of permissions.

Comment: hey bro can you tell what i should do